# How to achieve multiple emission color on one mesh..?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

I tried a color ramp node but its not working i also tried to mix two emission shader with mix node but result is not desired..

Like in the image

[image]

Comment: do you mean with a gradient effect?

Comment: Yes Sir Just like gradient with emission..

Answer (score 1):

1. create different material slots and materials (emission shader) for the same mesh
2. go to edit mode, select some faces
3. select a material slot and press "assign" button
   (this will assign the material only to selected faces)
   (eevee/cycles)